# jQuery Mouseover/MouseOut not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I a small question mark image on a page that if a user hovers over it shows and hides a Div containing help to explain the options in the drop down box beside which the question mark image sits.  The below is the html for the image and the Div - I havent included the text for the help Div but nothing fancy is done there - its all plain text with a few  statements and some 
 and then close the Div.

```
<img id="QuestionMark" src='/MyWebApp/view/images/icon/QuestionMark.png' height="15" />
<div id="HelpDiv" class="ui-widget-content Rounded hidden" style="position: fixed; z-index: 9999999; width: 100; padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px;">
```

This then is my javascript for either hiding or showing the Helper Div - I am using jQuery mouseover/mouseout

```
$("#QuestionMark").mouseover(function () {
    $('#HelpDiv').removeClass('hidden');
});

$("#QuestionMark").mouseout(function () {
    $('#HelpDiv').addClass('hidden');
});
```

If I load this in Chrome it works fine.  However when I am running in IE 9 it is not working?  I tried an Ctrl Refresh on the page to make sure I am pulling in my latest JS file and when I check Developer Tools in IE 9 and I find my script file I see that it does contain my above JS but it is not working.  Any one have any ideas?

Comment: you are using Zindex,check with the Div absolute position

Comment: what contains the hidden class?

Comment: ok - so this is kind off a bit of progress - as in I can see the Div - but now is isnt were I want - as the drop downs, etc and the image are in an accodion and now it loads inside would be no good for an end user of the UI

Comment: OMFG This bumped to homepage for a browser that does not matter in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo: http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

It works in IE9 for me. Make sure you have included jquery in your page or look for any errors in the console.

Comment: yeah def including the jQuery library - 1.7.2 imin, jquery ui 1.8.11 and some other jQuery libraries such as datatables, etc - cant understand why it is working in chrome and not IE though.

Comment: Does not it remove `hidden` class on mouseover?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#QuestionMark").mouseover(function () {
    $('#HelpDiv').show();
});

$("#QuestionMark").mouseout(function () {
    $('#HelpDiv').hide();
});
```